# Segmentation fault when querying for integers in Assembly

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

So i'm learning intel x86 assembly, and i'm trying to query a user for two integers, while rejecting if they enter an integer less than 0. I keep getting segmentation fault though, and am not sure why.

```
;.........................................................
;.........................................................
; sub-program to read an integer 
segment .Data
readmsg db "Enter two positive integers:", 0
negative_msg db "No, enter a POSITIVE integer.", 0
segment .text

int_cin:

push   ebp
mov    ebp,esp

mov    ecx, 2
mov    eax, readmsg
call   print_string

start:       
call   read_int
mov ebx, eax
cmp ebx, 0
jge skip
mov eax, negative_msg
call print_string
call print_nl
loop start
skip:
push ebx
dec ecx
loop start

pop  ebx
mov [Sec_Int], ebx
pop ebx
mov [First_Int], ebx

pop    ebp
ret
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of API you're using which provides `print_string`, `print_nl` and `read_int`, but I'm almost sure that you can't expect value of ECX register to be preserved during those calls (none of calling conventions I remember guarantee that). Thus your first mistake is that you expect ECX to only be changed by your own code but not by those external functions.

If I'm right and ECX changes unexpectedly, there's a good chance that `loop` instructions, waiting for ECX to become zero, will never stop jumping to the corresponding labels. That would give you an endless loop.

Looking further you'd see that inside that loop you push EBX to stack on each iteration. If the loop is endless, the stack would definitely overflow, resulting in segmentation fault.

P.S. If the first `loop start` doesn't go to `start` because ECX became zero, execution flow would continue to following instructions, which would push EBX to stack, decrease ECX once again (so it's -1 now), and loop back to start. Next time ECX would become zero (in ideal conditions) not that soon really.

P.P.S. You seem to be mixing up label addresses and values stored at those addresses, which may be another cause of segmentation faults. See how you first pass `[readmsg]` to `print_string`, and right after that you pass `readmsg` to the same functions. Looks very suspicious.

Comment: Okay, you're right on all of that, i fixed the segmentation faults, asnd now the loop is infinite like you said. I thought that ecx might not exactly overwrite what it's supposed to do just because I told it to. The plan is to let it loop continuously until it gets two positive integers, then pops those from the stack into two variables set up in the main .bss

Comment: If those external functions really do change ECX, consider either saving register value before making external calls and restoring it afterwards, or using in-memory variable to track your iterations.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't decrease ECX (or in-memory counter) on error, which you currently implicitly do with `loop` instruction.